Render manually created canvas elements in Preact
in my case I need to render a list of canvases in Preact manually created using document.createElement("canvas").
This is the code that generates it:
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = tmpCanvas.width;
canvas.height = tmpCanvas.height;
canvas.style.width = "100%";
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);   

I need to do it in this way since the incoming img is dynamically generated.
After that I would like to save the created canvas using a state (like setSnapshots(curr => [...curr, canvas])), and, in the end, in the render method, I would like to render all these canvases.
How should I do it? I've tried by simply adding something like <div>${snapshots}</div> or <div>${html(snapshots)}</div> but nothing worked.

Using refs would be the typical way to go about controlling the DOM from with Preact. Here's an example:
import { useRef, useEffect } from 'preact/hooks';

function MyComponent() {
    const ref = useRef(null); // create an empty reference

    useEffect(() => {
        const canvas = ref.current;
        if (canvas) {
            canvas.width = tmpCanvas.width; // manipulate the element
            canvas.height = tmpCanvas.height;
            //...
        }
    }, []);

    return <canvas ref={ref} />; // attach the reference to our element
}

Refs are references to DOM nodes which you can use like the above example to manipulate them as you need. Preact's docs on References
